# Lua Roblox respawn character dead

Tags: lua

How should I make this code work? The Judoon character must regenerate, (respawn) when I click on the wall but only when he is dead.[![Regenerate][1]][1] When I click on the wall, my Judoon character has to respawn but only when he is dead.

Also how can I introduce Regen Button, the script, be separate from the Judoon model, but it should work. If you put the script Regen into Workspace, separate from the Judoon folder, it will not work.

```
   local box = script.Parent


local debounce = false

-- DO NOT GROUP THIS WITH YOUR MODEL!

local everything = {Judoon}
local names = {Judoon}

local children = game.Workspace:children()
for i=1,#children do
    if (children[i].Name == "Judoon") then -- Replace the name with your models's name.
        table.insert(everything, children[i]:clone())
        table.insert(names, children[i].Name)
    end
end


function regen()
    for i=1,#everything do
        game.Workspace:findFirstChild(names[i]):remove() -- Dont mess with this stuff.
        new_thing = everything[i]:clone()
        new_thing.Parent = game.Workspace
        new_thing:makeJoints()
    end
end

function onClicked()  
  if Judoon:FindFirstChild("Judoon"):GetState() == Enum.HumanoidStateType.Dead then
     regen()
  end
end
        wait(15)-- This is how long it takes untill the regen button will work again.

        script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(104)


        debounce = false
end

 script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)

--This regen button was made by andymewborn,hope you like(d) it!

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLo3.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, if the humanoid is dead then regenerate.

```lua
function onClicked()  
  if Judoon:FindFirstChild("Judoon"):GetState() == Enum.HumanoidStateType.Dead then
     regen()
  end
end
```

New edit:

```lua
--[[
    1. Put this script inside the button
    2. Rename the modelname
    3. The model must be a child of Workspace
--]]
button = script.Parent
modelname = "Pk" -- Model name
model = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(modelname)
backup = model:Clone()

function Regen()
    local Old =game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(modelname)
    Old:Destroy()   
    local New = backup:Clone()
    model = New -- new changes made here
    New.Parent = workspace
    New:MakeJoints()
end

function onClicked()
    if button.BrickColor == BrickColor.new("Bright violet") then
        if model:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
            if model.Humanoid:GetState() == Enum.HumanoidStateType.Dead then
                Regen()
                print("removed and added")
            end
        end
        button.Regen:Play()
        button.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
        wait(3)
        button.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright violet")
    end
end

button.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(onClicked)
```

Comment: I think I renamed it, I posted all the code again, although I don't know why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Remember to define Judoon otherwise the script will not work.

Comment: I think the script is declared above, it works according to the model, only if you change the variables with Judoon. the model works when I click, the character respawn.The problem is that I should only put a condition on him when the NPC is dead, which is not very successful. this is a public script, just change the values with the appropriate model, https://www.roblox.com/library/162668750/Regen-Button-click-to-regen

Comment: I looked into that model and added few things. Now, it should work if you follow the instructions correctly.

Comment: Now the script seems to work well, although it seems to me that it does not change the color as it should (ie it does not change the color to black as it should and always remains Bright Violet), but it is good that now the character is respawned only when he is declared dead. however, after using the respawn function once, I cannot use it the second time, unless I put the + button (wall) script in the Judoon directory, if I do not enter (put) it in the directory I can only give the character respawn the only once. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: also, the print function ("removed and added"), which should do, that does not display anything. other than that, it works very well.

Comment: So the problem was that "model" variable was not being updated after when the dead character gets removed. I edited the code again.